# Error: #f is not a function [count-frac, (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), =]

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I'm trying to solve question 1.38 on SICP, and I encountered the bug as described in the title. Below is the description of the problem:

> In 1737, the Swiss mathematician Leonhard
> Euler published a memoir De Fractionibus Continuis, which
> included a continued-fraction expansion for *e − 2*, where
> *e* is the base of the natural logarithms. In this fraction, the
> Ni are all 1, and the Di are successively 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1,
> 6, 1, 1, 8, . . .. Write a program that uses your `cont-frac`
> procedure from Exercise 1.37 to approximate *e*, based on
> Euler’s expansion.

The `count-frac` procedure is intended to return the value of a *k*-term finite continued fraction, where parameters `n` and `d` are two procedures with the argument `i`.

Here is the mathematical way of expressing the fraction:

[image]

The procedure `d` defined below the procedure `count-frac` corresponds with parameter `d` in  `count-frac`.

Below is my code.

```
(define (count-frac n d k)
  (define (iter i result)
    (if(= i 0)
       result
       (iter (- i 1) (/ (n i)
                        (+ (d i)
                           result)))))
  (iter k 0))

(define (d i)
  (define (int-div x y)
    (/ (- x (mod x y))
       y))
  (if ((= (mod i 3) 1) or (= (mod i 3) 0))
     1
     (+ 2 (* 2 (int-div i 3)))))

(count-frac (lambda (x) 1.0)
            d
            11)
```

Any suggestions on resolving the bug are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In your function `d`, you have

```
    ((= (mod i 3) 1) or (= (mod i 3) 0))
```

This is, again,

```
    (  (= (mod i 3) 1)
       or
       (= (mod i 3) 0)  )
```

The result of evaluating `(= (mod i 3) 1)` is used as a function, and is called with the other two arguments.

Apparently that result was `#f`, and that is definitely not a function.

Maybe you intended it to be

```
    ( or
       (= (mod i 3) 1)
       (= (mod i 3) 0)  )
```

Now `or` is called with the other two values as arguments, which is a valid call to make.

Comment: Thank you so much! Eventually, I'm not used to the programming structure of lisp.

Comment: Simply, the structure is *prefix*: function first, arguments later - as is quite usual. Just one opening paren moves over the function, to the left.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by having a constant in the first place in a pair of parentheses. Scheme (or any dialect of Lisp, for that matter) expects a function  in this location.

```
(1 2 3)  ; an error, '1 is not a function'
(#f #t)  ; an error, '#f is not a function'
```

There are many ways to edit and run Scheme code. My preference is for Dr Racket, which is for the very similar Racket language. By putting the tag `#lang scheme` in the first line you have a very reasonable Scheme development system.

When I run the code, it immediately shows the problem. Your 'or' function is infix, when it should be prefix - a natural problem caused by switching between infix and postfix languages.

[image]

Comment: I saw it stated several times on SO by authoritative Racket sources that #scheme should not be used, is not for Scheme, is some internal leftover from the past, and either #racket or #r5rs etc. should be used instead.